# how can I use cloudfront with multiple beanstalk environments?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

right now I have an app that runs on several beanstalk environments in different regions and use route53 geo location records for routing

I want to use cloudfront for these environments

Can I create a cloudfront for each environment and route to them with route53? Or can I create a single cloudfront and connect all of the beanstalks to it? Do I have to use cloudfront lambda to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I create a cloudfront for each environment and route to them with route53?

CloudFront and Route53 don't relate to each other.
Route53 gives URL of an application (deployed to Beanstalk in this case) to end users. When users open this URL, they will see something rendered. This something uses resources. These resources can be stored in CloudFront CDN or can be stored in your application.
You can see that Route53 doesn't collaborate with CloudFront here.